# When should one use RegionFunction with ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, regions, parametric-functions

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html), "`RegionFunction` is an option for plotting functions that specifies the region to include in the plot drawn", and it can be used with `ParametricPlot3D`.

However, when using the latter command, one can also directly set variable plot limits, e.g., by writing `{v, -f[u], f[u]}` for some appropriate function `f[u]`. I am wondering whether there is any difference in doing this with respect to using `RegionFunction`.

For example, in the case below, the two plots produce exactly the same figure.

```
surface[u_, v_] := {Cos[v] Cos[u], Cos[v] Sin[u], Sin[v]}

f[u_] := u/2

ParametricPlot3D[surface[u, v], {u, 0, Pi}, {v, -f[u], f[u]}]

ParametricPlot3D[surface[u, v], {u, 0, Pi}, {v, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
 RegionFunction -> (-#4/2 < #5 < #4/2 &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some differences. For example, if we set `f[u_]:=-u/2` and `u` in the interval `{u,-Pi/2,Pi}`, then the three pictures below are different.

```
surface[u_, v_] := {Cos[v] Cos[u], Cos[v] Sin[u], Sin[v]};
f[u_] := -u/2;
a = ParametricPlot3D[surface[u, v], {u, -Pi/2, Pi}, {v, -f[u], f[u]}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
b = ParametricPlot3D[surface[u, v], {u, -Pi/2, Pi}, {v, -10, 10}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, -f[u] <= v <= f[u]], 
   PlotRange -> All];
c = ParametricPlot3D[surface[u, v], {u, -Pi/2, Pi}, {v, -10, 10}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, -u/2 <= v <= u/2], 
   PlotRange -> All];
GraphicsRow[{a, b, c}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not empty if one writes `RegionFunction -> (-#4/2 <= #5 <= #4/2 &)` instead. Or, equivalently, `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, -u/2 <= v <= u/2]`.

Comment: @MK7 Please see the updated.

Comment: I cannot make sense of plots a and c being different. Could you please provide some detail?

Comment: @MK7  It seems that ` {v, -f[u], f[u]}` means that `v` is between `-f[u]` and `f[u]`, is difference from  `-f[u]<=v<=f[u]`

Comment: OK I see it now. When `u < 0`, `RegionFunction` in your third `ParametricPlot3D` returns `False`. On the other hand, in the first `ParametricPlot3D`, replacing `{v, -f[u], f[u]}` with `{v, f[u], -f[u]}` does not affect the solution.